# Tool to manage IP map?

Tags: networking, active-directory, documentation

Is there a tool which can manage the maintenance of an IP map?

If no, it is possible to make a Powershell script which can get hostnames and their IPs, but it'd be nice if a tool exists to do this for me. Maintaining an IP map is becoming a big bottleneck.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to IPAM?

Comment: I just googled IPAM and that looks very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use static DHCP assignments?  Then your map becomes the territory.  Failing that, if you use DHCP your DHCP server should have an IP map.